# create a .row.cells line for length of <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hello I want to create a script that takes the amount of (tr) it finds then creates these 3 lines of code but changes the number in them based on the number it gets of (tr) here is an example:

I have a line of code that counts the table rows in the table (after I press a button) minus the table header (th):

```
var rowCount = $('#items-table tr').length - 1;
```

what I want to do is say for example the number I get is 3, I want to duplicate these 3 lines of code and change the variable and the number inside them.

Here are the 3 lines of code I want to duplicate:

```
table = document.getElementById("items-table");
var cell1 = table.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
var cell2 = table.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
var cell3 = table.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML;
```

what I want to change is the var so I can define it later so if I got 3 this is what I would want the output to be:

```
var cell1 = table.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
var cell2 = table.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
var cell3 = table.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML;

var cell4 = table.rows[2].cells[0].innerHTML;
var cell5 = table.rows[2].cells[1].innerHTML;
var cell6 = table.rows[2].cells[2].innerHTML;

var cell7 = table.rows[3].cells[0].innerHTML;
var cell8 = table.rows[3].cells[1].innerHTML;
var cell9 = table.rows[3].cells[2].innerHTML;
```

How would I go about doing this? I would also want to great a variable that could represent all the var cell(s) like this

```
tableData = []   tableData.append(var cell7 = etc..)
```

so then I could take the tableData and:

```
localStorage.setItem("tableData", tableData);
```

so then I could call this table data variable inside another html file.
I would also like to localStorage the variable lines themselves so I could call them individually as-well.

```
localStorage.setItem("item-name-1", cell1);
```

How would I got about doing this?

Important Note: At the start of my html page the table is empty. I then append the data using several inputs and an add button.

Any Help is appreciated Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for an *array*, in your case probably an array of arrays:

```
let cells = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementById("items-table").rows, row => {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(row.cells, cell => cell.innerHTML);
});
```

Live Example:

```js
let cells = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementById("items-table").rows, row => {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(row.cells, cell => cell.innerHTML);
});
console.log("cells:", cells);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="items-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 2 Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3 Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3 Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3 Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4 Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 4 Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 4 Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `Array.prototype.map.call` part lets us use `Array`'s built-in [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on `rows` and `cells` even though they aren't arrays, but are array-like. Alternatively, you could actually turn them into arrays with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
let cells = Array.from(document.getElementById("items-table").rows).map(row => {
    return Array.from(row.cells).map(cell => cell.innerHTML);
});
```

Live Example:

```js
let cells = Array.from(document.getElementById("items-table").rows).map(row => {
    return Array.from(row.cells).map(cell => cell.innerHTML);
});
console.log("cells:", cells);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="items-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 2 Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3 Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3 Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3 Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4 Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 4 Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 4 Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Storing that in local storage is simply a call to `JSON.stringify`:

```
localStorage.setItem("tableData", JSON.stringify(cells));
```

Restoring it from local storage:

```
var cells = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableData") || "[]");
```

(The `|| "[]"` part provides a default — an empty array — for when there is no tableData stored.)

Comment: What does your script basically do because I don't see you mention rowCount at all @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj - There's no need, `map` (or `Array.from`) looks at the `length` of `rows` (and `cells` in a row).

Comment: Shouldn't `"[]"` be `[]` to assign an empty array?

Comment: @MarkBaijens - No, it's within the argument to `JSON.parse`. You can either do `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableData") || "[]")` or `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableData")) || [])`. The latter relies on a couple of implicit things, though: That `getItem` returns `null` when the item doesn't exist, and passing `null` into `JSON.parse` results in it getting coerced to `"null"`, which then gets parsed as `null`. :-) I go back and forth whether to do the default within the `JSON.parse` argument or on its result.

Comment: Ow sorry read it wrong. It's still early here. Thought it was outside the parse function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok I see what would be the variable that I would use to call each cell because I have info in the table that the cell will represent that I will call later in another js file  like for example: cell1 = T-Shirt Black,   cell2= Large, cell3=Any Size,  cell 4 = orange hoodie, cell5= Small, cell6= Any Color, and so on....

Comment: what would I call to use the info stored in the cell   cell1, cell2? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj - You use array indexes; [more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), `cells[x][y]` where `x` is the row (0 = first, 1 = second) and `y` is the cell in that row (0 = first, 1 = second, ...). The value of the first row's first cell is `cells[0][0]`; the value of the first row's second cell is `cells[0][1]`; the value of the third row's second cell is `cells[2][1]`, etc.

Comment: This code is smart but unfortunatly it is not the code I am looking for.. at the start of my html page the table is empty and I append that data using a couple of inputs and an add button @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj - Then you'd rebuild the `cells` array after adding. Or just access the information in the DOM instead of duplicating it to arrays.

Comment: I get this error when I run your code and I try and console.log(cells[0][0]);      Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj - Then you must have some error; see the live example in the answer. Of course, you can't access `cells[0][0]` unless you do actually have at least one row. `cells.length` tells you how many rows you have. More about arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable with an array:

```
var table, cell, i, r, noofrows;
table = document.getElementById("items-table");
noofrows = table.rows.length;

for (i = 0, r = 0, cell = []; r < noofrows; i++, r++) {
  cell[i] = table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML;
  cell[i+1] = table.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML;
  cell[i+2] = table.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML;
}
```

Then the first cell will be assigned to the variable `cell[0]`, the second will be `cell[1]`, etc. For example, `document.write(cell[0])` will write "Item" (from your previous question).

`document.write(cell[1])` will write "Size".

`document.write(cell[3])` will write the first cell of row 2.

Comment: I get this when I try and run the code       Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: I then changed   noofrows = $('#items-table tr').length    then I got Cannot read property '0' of undefined   for    cell[i] = table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML;       @Intelta

Comment: Could I maybe email my entire code so you can see why its not working???  @Intelta

Comment: Is the table ID still "items-table"?

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table/ do all of the cells have content?

Comment: Yes I add the rows in then I press a button that should alert me the data but it doesnt   @Intelta

Comment: codepen wont work for me can I have your email??  or email me wojprod@gmail.com   if u don't want to reveal your email

Comment: have you gotten a chance to look at my email?

Comment: Doing it now. -

Comment: Hey I might have tracked down the problem after I add in all the <td> i then inspect the page and go to the console where i type console.log(cell[4]);  and I get this error "cell is not defined" @Intelta